# How to generate additional Properties.Settings.Default in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the question about Properties.Settings.Default generation. By default there are only `defaultInstance` is generating in Settings.Designer.cs . How to add `Properties.Settings.Default.WindowState` and for example `Properties.Settings.Default.WindowWidth;` in this auto-generated Settings.Designer.cs ?

1. UPDATE
   -the problem was solved by the addition of AppConfig where all needed properties described.
   -Settings.settings modification (perhaps this file is generated automatically) thanks to Monty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Properties folder in your solution project. In that folder you will find the Settings.settings file. Doubleclick it and it will show a designer in which you can add additional settings. These added settings are then persisted to the designer file, so you can call them from code.

Good luck.

Comment: I have add them but it seems that something else is needed - Error 'MyProj.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'WindowState' and no extension method 'WindowState' accepting a first argument of type 'MyProj.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It seems that I need also modify app.config to have needed effect

Comment: Did you add a property named WindowState to the designer pane (not the file) in Visual Studio?

Comment: To add WindowState in the Settings.settings, clic on the combobox from the Types and choose BROWSER . In the Window , write  manually System.Windows.WindowState